# Is it good idea use static class AppContext?

Tags: java, android

I found in one of github [project](https://github.com/blandware/android-atleap/blob/master/atleap-core/src/main/java/com/blandware/android/atleap/AppContext.java) class:

```
public class AppContext {

    private static Context sContext;
    private static Application sApplication;

    public static Application getApplication() {
        if (sApplication == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("AppContext.setApplication was not called in Application.onCreate() method. " +
                    "Please inherit your application from the com.blandware.android.atleap.BaseApplication class.");
        }

        return sApplication;
    }

    public static void setApplication(Application application) {
        sApplication = application;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        if (sContext == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("AppContext.setContext was not called in Application.onCreate() method. " +
                    "Please inherit your application from the com.blandware.android.atleap.BaseApplication class.");
        }

        return sContext;
    }


    public static void setContext(Context context) {
        sContext = context;
    }
}
```

It seams create, don't need more pass context to static function etc. But I'm worried about memory leaks. Can AppContext make it? When i shoud use Aplication context when activity context or view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Application object can not leak.  There is always exactly one Application object for every app.  It looks like the author is just using this class to make it easy to access in places where another Context is not available to be used to call getApplicationContext() to get the Application object.

Context, on the other hand, could be an Activity or a Service, and those really should not be stored beyond their lifetime.  You will have to look at exactly which Context objects are being stored here to find out if there is a leak.

Comment: can you explain ```You will have to look at exactly which Context objects are being stored here to find out if there is a leak.```?

Comment: I'm saying that it's impossible to know with just the code here if there is going to be a problem.  You have to look at how it's being used to know if there is going to be a potential problem leaking objects past their expected lifetime.